# Reading (assigning) txt.file values in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, java-io

**Update:**
I'm using **'\n'** to diverse each line in the saveGame method, which is specified in the API. This means readLine should correctly find each individual line in the file, assign its value and close after it has read the last line. However, I still get "null" (NullPointerException) as output...

This is how null is specified in the API:

> **(readLine) Returns:**
>
> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any
>   line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been
>   reached

---

**I'm trying to read a txt file and assign its lines into an int [][] array.**

This is an example on how my **savegame.txt** file looks like:

```
0 

0

-1

0

1

-1

1

0

0
```

Every line represents a int-value. My saveGame method writes the current int-values of the array "gameBoard" into the above shown file. This example represents the following game state:

```
  |   | O
```

---

```
  | X | O
```

---

```
X |   |
```

---

However, when I try to read the savegame.txt file with my loadGame method, which assigns each individual gameBoard-position [0][0] to [2][2] its respective values, I get **null** as output and the game starts with an empty array. From my logic, my loadGame method should read every line seperately and parse its String-value into an Integer which than can be interpreted by my int[][] array gameBoard. **I wonder why this does not work correctly.**

**FileManagement.class**

```
package storagePack;

import structurePack.Board;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * The FileManagement-Class is responsible for the saving and loading of gamedata.
 * It saves the current gameBoard and reads it with the loadGame Method.
 */

public class FileManagement {
    static String filename = "Savegame.txt";

/**
 * Schema:
 * (0,0) | (0,1) | (0,2)
 * (1,0) | (1,1) | (1,2)
 * (2,0) | (2,1) | (2,2)
 */
/**
 * @param gameBoard, the currently active Array from the Board.class.
 * @throws Exception, FileNotFoundException
 */
public static void saveGame(int[][] gameBoard) throws Exception {
    //serialization
    PrintWriter writer;
    try {

        writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), false);
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gameBoard.length; j++) {
                int entry = gameBoard[i][j];
                writer.print(entry);
                writer.println('\n');
            }

        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * @throws Exception, FileNotFoundException
 */
public static void loadGame() throws Exception {
    //deserialization
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (fileReader);
    try {
        structurePack.Board.gameBoard[0][0] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
        structurePack.Board.gameBoard[0][1] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
        structurePack.Board.gameBoard[0][2] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
        structurePack.Board.gameBoard[1][0] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
        structurePack.Board.gameBoard[1][1] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
        structurePack.Board.gameBoard[1][2] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
        structurePack.Board.gameBoard[2][0] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
        structurePack.Board.gameBoard[2][1] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
        structurePack.Board.gameBoard[2][2] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
        fileReader.close();
        bufferedReader.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

**readLine API-Documentation**

```
public String readLine()
                throws IOException

Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Returns:
A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

Throws:
IOException - If an I/O error occurs

See Also:
Files.readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.charset.Charset)
```

Comment: if you are reading from a file, why are you using a `Scanner(System.in)`?

Comment: try `e.printStackTrace();` instead of `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` . This would be good practice regarding exception-displaying in the console and will quite likely help you.

Comment: Oh, I thought that I could use a scanner... do I have to use BufferedReader?https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: Use FileReader and BufferedReader in order to read text files in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change loadGame method as below:

```
public static void loadGame() throws Exception {
    //deserialization

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    structurePack.Board.gameBoard[0][0] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
    structurePack.Board.gameBoard[0][1] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
    structurePack.Board.gameBoard[0][2] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
    structurePack.Board.gameBoard[1][0] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
    structurePack.Board.gameBoard[1][1] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
    structurePack.Board.gameBoard[1][2] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
    structurePack.Board.gameBoard[2][0] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
    structurePack.Board.gameBoard[2][1] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
    structurePack.Board.gameBoard[2][2] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
}
```

This code might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Dave at first answer was accepted..now its not .? is there anything wrong?

Comment: I still get the NullPointerException, but I will re-mark your answer. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: The issue was actually caused by an internal method in my Board.class, the loadGame Method worked perfectly. After I fixed that, I'm now able to properly load the Savegame.txt file. Thank you.